# MySQL - SELECT rows between Yesterday 3pm and Today 7:30am

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return rows between yesterday 15:00 and today 07:30, but can't seem to get it work.
I've tried the following two methods, but they haven't worked.

Note:

- Getdate() should be CURDATE() in MySQL
- TIMESERIAL is denied to my user account in the database

Code Examples:

```
where dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0,Getdate()),0)- 1
and dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0,Getdate()),0)- 1) + '23:59:59'

where [Table].[Date Time] Between Date()-1 + TimeSerial(18,0,0) 
                              And Date()   + TimeSerial(18,0,0)
```

Comment: Please clarify which RDBMS you're using, and see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your code samples are SQL Server.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: It says MySQL in the title..
@GordonLinoff Yes I'm sure. I copied the examples from the internet, so they might be written in a different language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `DATE_ADD` and then `INTERVAL n HOUR OR MINUTE`.

Please check the attached fiddle. http://rextester.com/JIXU4144

```
select DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL -9 HOUR);
select DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 450 minute);


select * from temp
where createdOn between '2018-08-28 15:00:00' and '2018-08-29 07:30:00';

select * from temp
where createdOn between DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL -9 HOUR) and  DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 450 minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can do:

```
where col >= curdate() - interval 1 day + interval 15 hour and
      col < curdate() + interval 7.5 * 60 minute
```

You can also write this a bit more readably as:

```
where col >= curdate() - interval 1 day + interval 15 hour and
      col < curdate() + interval '7:30' hour_minute
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have high enough access to use TIMESERIAL()

Comment: @MichielvanDijk . . . I interpreted that as the name of your column.